# Enviroment gets increasingly brighter when running (unity)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Am a newbie to Unity, was following a Youtube tutorial on creating a endless runner 3D game. was trying to get it to repeat section. But problem is, the environment get's brighter and brighter once the game runs. What is wrong with the code below? Thanks! :)

```
    
    public class GenerateLevel : MonoBehaviour
 {
     public GameObject[] section;
     public int zPos = 39;
     public bool creatingSection = false;
  
     public int secNum;
 
    
     void Update()
     {
         if (creatingSection == false)
         {
             creatingSection = true;
             StartCoroutine(GenerateSection());
         }
     }
     IEnumerator GenerateSection()
     {
      
         secNum = Random.Range(0, 3);
         Instantiate(section[secNum], new Vector3(0, 0, zPos), Quaternion.identity);
         zPos += 39;
         yield return new WaitForSeconds(2);
         creatingSection= false;
     } 
}
```

Before

[image]

When running

[image]

Comment: Your sections seem to contain directional lights => the more sections you spawn the more total light ...

Comment: Also in general please use the correct tags! Note that [`unityscript`](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/unityscript/info) is or better **was** a JavaScript flavor like custom language used in early Unity versions and is long **deprecated** by now! Your code is clearly in c# ..

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks fine. So the only thing that could cause this is, you keep **instantiating** a new random block that might contains a **directional light** every 2 seconds.

Your scene should only have 1 directional light. So check in your section GameObjects, make sure it doesn't have any directional light in them.